# Looking for a better cross platform notification system

Tags: windows, android, linux, notification

I'm currently looking for a better replacement for growl for windows + gntp-send for sending notifications from a headless linux box to my windows box (and others.)

Right now, [GFW](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/) does a few things well - with [appropriate plugins](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiEooa0v5jTAhWLtI8KHTwYDVwQFgg3MAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2F1039396%2Fhow-do-i-get-growl-for-windows-to-use-native-windows-8-10-notifications&usg=AFQjCNEU9v0XM_1GlesL4MKExtdmYYkRgg&sig2=https://superuser.com/questions/1039396/how-do-i-get-growl-for-windows-to-use-native-windows-8-10-notifications), in mostly integrates into windows in an almost native functionality. With a known host, I can send notifications. It mostly works - I use it with [gntp-send](https://superuser.com/a/477334/10165).

That said, I'd like a few things more - like being able to send notifications to an android phone with an unknown IP address, and the ability to store and retry messages.

The bare minimum here would be a linux growl forwarder that allows for subscriptions and runs purely in command line. Ubuntu 16.10 would be a good target OS.

What I probably *really* need is a protocol that has support for multiple targets for notifications. The workflow I see is this.

1. Run a command line application that takes a title, message body and a target - and targets a system which runs a forwarder/main server - running ubuntu without a GUI.
2. This system will forward this or allow systems to subscribe to messages - Growl for windows does this, but runs on windows and has a gui
3. Storing and forwarding would be nice but optional
4. notifications are received on target systems and subscribers

I'd *need* windows and android support for systems receiving notifications and linux support for the system sending the messages and acting as a forwarder. I'd like the linux side *purely* cli and not being tied to any DE, X or wayland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cobbled together something around a [matrix-synapse homeserver](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse) and the [navi notification bot for it](https://github.com/madmax28/navi)

Navi's used to send notifications to my homeserver. That's in a private room my regular user can see and as such I get notifications for my matrix clients.

I currently have [riot](https://matrix.org/docs/projects/client/riot.html) as a webui so I can check notifications on my PC (I'd need something better eventually) and the android client on my phone.

Since Navi and synapse act on a private chat room, I can look up *when* a notification was made as well.

Its not *perfect* - GFW gives me native toast notifications but matrix is *currently supported*, I'm not limited to my home network, and I have a lot more flexibility. It is *slightly* overkill - but I suppose its necessary to get all my requirements met.